# Angular directive for form elements

Tags: angularjs, input, directive

I want to create directive which will be used for form elements like input,textarea,select...

My code:

```
app.directive('input', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        priority: -1000,
        require: '^?required',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

            element.on('focus', function (e) {
                element.addClass('validate');
            });

        }
    };
});
```

When I try to use common directive it doesn't work but don't have idea why...

```
<input common-directive type="text" name="name" placeholder="Firstname" ng-model="profile.name" ng-minlength="2" required />
```

Comment: Do you see any error in console? if not then you dont have a template to show the element on the page.

Comment: Any error... it's strange because it works when my directive is input or textarea...

Comment: your directive is called `input` and restricted to `E` (Element), so it will only work on `<input>`s. Rename it to `'commonDirective'` and restrict it to `'A'` (Attribute)

Comment: Ahh it works... Thank you!